# Buffer API: Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: curl

Following [their documentation](https://buffer.com/developers/api/updates), I'm sending the following POST curl request:

```
curl -X POST -d'{"access_token":"MY_TOKEN","profile_ids":["PROFILE_ID_1","PROFILE_ID_2"],"text":"Look at the forecast"}' https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

However I get the following response:

```
Disallowed Key Characters.
```

Any ideas what should I change in my request?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do the curl request:

```
curl -X POST -d'access_token=MY_TOKEN&profile_ids%5B%5D=ID_1&profile_ids%5B%5D=ID_2&text=Look%20at%20the%20forecast' https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json … -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Source: https://twitter.com/buffer/status/1011278225513869314